# X and Y are two standard normal distribution what is the joint probability that X falls within (0, 1) and X+Y falls within (0, 2)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am learning the sum of independent random variables and come across this problem. Suppose $Z = X+Y$, both $X$ and $Y$ are standard normal distribution, that is $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y \sim N(0,1)$, and they are independent from each other. The question asks what is $P(X\in(0,1), Z\in (0,2))$?

This is how I think of this, for $Z=X+Y\in(0,2)$, we need $Y\in(-X, 2-X)$, and since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, we can say:
$$
P(X\in(0,1), Z\in (0,2)) = \int_0^1 \int_{-x}^{2-x} f_X(x) f_Y(y) dy dx\\
=\int_0^1 f_X(x) \int_{-x}^{2-x} f_Y(y) dy dx\\
=\int_0^1 f_X(x) [F_Y(2-x)- F_Y(-x)] dx
$$

Is the above the correct way of thinking it? And can I go further without having to go through the integrals on the error function?

Comment: First, try to find the z scores of $X$ and $Z$. $\sigma_Z=\sqrt{\text{var}(X)+\text{var(Y)}}, \mu_Z=\mu_X+\mu_Y$. Then, $z_Z=\frac{Z-\mu_Z}{\sigma_Z}, z_X=\frac{X-\mu_x}{\sigma_X}$ and find $P(0<X<1)P(0<Z<2)$ using a z table. Tell me if this is not it.

Comment: Can we say that $P(0<X<1, 0<Z<2) = P(0<X<1)P(0<Z<2)$ since $X$ is independent from $Y$ but not $Z$ as $Z=X+Y$.